# Hippomock static function with overload, how to use ExpectCallFuncOverload?

Tags: c++, mocking, overloading, hippomocks

With the following class:

```
class Math {
public:
    static int Add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    static int Add(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a + b + c;
    }
};
```

How to use ExpectCallFuncOverload?

I try

```
#include <hippomock.h>

int main() {
    HippoMock::MockRepository mocks;
    mocks.ExpectCallFuncOverload(Math::Add).Return(5);

    Math::Add(2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

gcc tells "call of overloaded 'RegisterExpect_...' is ambiguous"

How to tell Hippomock which overload we want to use?
I don't find anything in the documentation

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

Use a cast to determine the function to use

```
mocks.ExpectCallFuncOverload((int (*)(int, int))Math::Add).Return(5);
```